# php regex - Matching with space

Tags: php, regex

I have a string:

```
 onchange = "(getURLVar(\'route\') == \'checkout/cart\' || getURLVar(\'route\') == \'checkout/checkout\') ? location = \'index.php?route=checkout/cart&remove=46\' : $(\'#cart\').load(\'index.php?route=module/cart&remove=46\' + \' #cart > *\');
```

how i can get value of     `*onchange ="...any..."*   and    *location attrib  =    location = \'index.php?route=checkout/cart&remove=46\' :*`

with php regex
?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Is your string named `onchange`?  Or is that the contents of your string?

Comment: Since this string, at it's most basic level, it HTML content: [You cannot parse non-regular languages with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732454)

Comment: i need anything  onchang = "...here..."   and anything after location word

Comment: There seems to be only a single `"`. The other part of the pair isn't visible? Also, would be better if you put your attempt, some more sample input and their corresponding desired outputs.

Comment: code= location = \'index.php?route=checkout/cart&remove=46\' :      after with regex === index.php?route=checkout/cart&remove=46

Comment: can you show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, but maybe this is what you're looking for.

```
$string = 'onchange=\'trueorfalse\'&location=\'index.php?route=checkout/cart&remove=46\'';

preg_match_all("/onchange='([^']+)'[.]*&location='([^']+)'/",$string, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => onchange='trueorfalse'&location='index.php?route=checkout/cart&remove=46'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => trueorfalse
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => index.php?route=checkout/cart&remove=46
        )
)
```